# How can i make my code work for Blackberry work for iOS and the most recent blackberry iteration?

Tags: email, blackberry, html-email, blackberry-simulator

Header not showing up for blackberry work ios and the wrapper isn't being respected for blackberry email. Padding is also not respected in blackberry email for buttons.

I've tried border, align, adding a wrapper div for the weird space after that appears around images. I've given up on responsiveness for those clients but I would like to just look cohesive.

```
html,
body {
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
height: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
* {
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
/* What it does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
margin:0 !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
table,
td {
mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}
/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. */
table {
border: 0;
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse
}
/* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
img {
-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
}
/* What it does: Prevents Windows 10 Mail from underlining links despite inline CSS. Styles for underlined links should be inline. */
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
/* What it does: A work-around for email clients automatically linking certain text strings. */
/* iOS */
a[x-apple-data-detectors],
.unstyle-auto-detected-links a,
.aBn {
border-bottom: 0 !important;
cursor: default !important;
color: inherit !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
font-size: inherit !important;
font-family: inherit !important;
font-weight: inherit !important;
line-height: inherit !important;
}
u + #body a,        /* Gmail */
#MessageViewBody a  /* Samsung Mail */
{
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
line-height: inherit;
}
/* What it does: Prevents Gmail from changing the text color in conversation threads. */
.im {
color: inherit !important;
}
/* What it does: Prevents Gmail from displaying an download button on large, non-linked images. */
.a6S {
display: none !important;
opacity: 0.01 !important;
}
/* If the above doesn't work, add a .g-img class to any image in question. */
img.g-img + div {
display:none !important;
}
/* What it does: Removes right gutter in Gmail iOS app.  */
/* Create one of these media queries for each additional viewport size you'd like to fix */
.email-container {
width: 100% !important;
}
/* iPhone 4, 4S, 5, 5S, 5C, and 5SE */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px) {
u ~ div .email-container {
min-width: 320px !important;
}
}
/* iPhone 6, 6S, 7, 8, and X */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) {
u ~ div .email-container {
min-width: 375px !important;
}
}
/* iPhone 6+, 7+, and 8+ */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) {
u ~ div .email-container {
min-width: 414px !important;
}
}
</style>
<!-- What it does: Helps DPI scaling in Outlook 2007-2013 -->
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
   <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      <o:AllowPNG/>
      <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
   </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
<!-- CSS Reset : END -->
<!-- Progressive Enhancements : BEGIN -->
<style>
   /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons and tags */
   .s-btn__primary:hover {
   background: #0077CC !important;
   border-color: #0077CC !important;
   }
   .s-btn__white:hover {
   background: #EFF0F1 !important;
   border-color: #EFF0F1 !important;
   }
   .s-btn__outlined:hover {
   background: rgba(0,119,204,.05) !important;
   color: #005999 !important;
   }
   .s-tag:hover,
   .post-tag:hover {
   border-color: #cee0ed !important;
   background: #cee0ed !important;
   }
   /* What it does: Styles markdown links that we can't write inline CSS for. */
   .has-markdown a,
   .has-markdown a:visited {
   color: #0077CC !important;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   }
   /* What it does: Styles markdown code blocks that we can't write inline CSS for. */
   code {
   padding: 1px 5px;
   background-color: #EFF0F1;
   color: #242729;
   font-size: 13px;
   line-height: inherit;
   font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, sans-serif;
   }
   pre {
   margin: 0 0 15px;
   line-height: 17px;
   background-color: #EFF0F1;
   padding: 4px 8px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   }
   pre code {
   margin: 0 0 15px;
   padding: 0;
   line-height: 17px;
   background-color: none;
   }
   /* What it does: Styles markdown blockquotes that we can't write inline CSS for. */
   blockquote {
   margin: 0 0 15px;
   padding: 4px 10px;
   background-color: #FFF8DC;
   border-left: 2px solid #ffeb8e;
   }
   blockquote p {
   padding: 4px 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
   }
   /* What it does: Rounds corners in email clients that support it */
   .bar {
   border-radius: 5px;
   }
   .btr {
   border-top-left-radius: 5px;
   border-top-right-radius: 5px;
   }
   .bbr {
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
   }
   @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
   /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
   .stack-column,
   .stack-column-center {
   display: block !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   max-width: 100% !important;
   direction: ltr !important;
   }
   /* And center justify these ones. */
   .stack-column-center {
   text-align: center !important;
   }
   /* Hides things in small viewports. */
   .hide-on-mobile {
   display: none !important;
   max-height: 0 !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   visibility: hidden !important;
   }
   /* What it does: Utility classes to reduce spacing for smaller viewports. */
   .sm-p-none  {padding: 0 !important;}
   .sm-pt-none {padding-top: 0 !important;}
   .sm-pb-none {padding-bottom: 0 !important;}
   .sm-pr-none {padding-right: 0 !important;}
   .sm-pl-none {padding-left: 0 !important;}
   .sm-px-none {padding-left: 0 !important; padding-right: 0 !important;}
   .sm-py-none {padding-top: 0 !important; padding-bottom: 0 !important;}
   .sm-p   {padding: 20px !important;}
   .sm-pt  {padding-top: 20px !important;}
   .sm-pb  {padding-bottom: 20px !important;}
   .sm-pr  {padding-right: 20px !important;}
   .sm-pl  {padding-left: 20px !important;}
   .sm-px  {padding-left: 20px !important; padding-right: 20px !important;}
   .sm-py  {padding-top: 20px !important; padding-bottom: 20px !important;}
   .sm-mb  {margin-bottom: 20px !important;}
   /* What it does: Utility classes to kill border radius for smaller viewports. Used mainly on the email's main container(s). */
   .bar,
   .btr,
   .bbr {
   border-top-left-radius: 0;
   border-top-right-radius: 0;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
   }
   /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
   .center-on-narrow {
   text-align: center !important;
   display: block !important;
   margin-left: auto !important;
   margin-right: auto !important;
   float: none !important;
   }
   table.center-on-narrow {
   display: inline-block !important;
   }
   }
</style>
<!-- Progressive Enhancements : END -->
</head>
<!--
   The email background color is defined in three places, just below. If you change one, remember to change the others.
   1. body tag: for most email clients
   2. center tag: for Gmail and Inbox mobile apps and web versions of Gmail, GSuite, Inbox, Yahoo, AOL, Libero, Comcast, freenet, Mail.ru, Orange.fr
   3. mso conditional: For Windows 10 Mail
   -->
<body width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; background: #f3f3f5; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
   <center style="width: 100%; background: #f3f3f5;">
   <!--[if mso | IE]>
   <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #f3f3f5;">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <![endif]-->
         <!-- Visually Hidden Preview Text : BEGIN -->
         <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; font-family: sans-serif;">
            We are committed to being the leading commercial and wealth bank for the private economy in the U.S., working hard every day to help your realize your ambitions. Enhancing our capital markets capabilities for commercial and wealth clients is an important part of being able to deliver excellence for our 
         </div>
         <!-- Visually Hidden Preview Text : END -->
         <div class="email-container" style="max-width: 680px; margin: 0 auto;">
         <!--[if mso]>
         <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" align="center">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <![endif]-->
         <table aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px;">
         <!-----------------------------
            EMAIL BODY : BEGIN

            ------------------------------>
         <!-- Primary Email Body : BEGIN -->
   <tr>
      <td style="padding: 30px; background-color: #ffffff;" class="sm-p btr">
         <div dir="rtl" style="display: table; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; font-size: 0;">
            <!--[if mso]>
            <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="620">
               <tr>
                  <td align="left" valign="top" width="128">
                     <![endif]-->
                     <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 -1px; max-width: 680px; min-width:100px; vertical-align: top;" class="stack-column">
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                           <!-- White text : BEGIN -->
                           <tr>
                              <td dir="ltr" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #fff; text-align: left; padding-right: 0px;">
                                 <p>
                                    We are committed to being the leading commercial and wealth bank for the private economy in the U.S., working hard every day to help your realize your ambitions. Enhancing our capital markets capabilities for commercial and wealth clients is an important part of being able to deliver excellence for our clients every day. Last week, we announced that we have reached an agreement to acquire Cleary Gull<br><br>
                                 </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <!-- White text : END -->
                           <!-- View in Browser : BEGIN -->
                           <tr>
                              <td style="padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; font-family: arial, sans-serif; color: #9199A1; text-align: left;">
                                 <a style="color: #9199A1; text-decoration: underline;" href="http://++ViewHTMLCustom++ ">View in browser</a>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <!-- View in Browser : END -->
                           <!-- Hero Image : BEGIN -->
                           <tr>
                              <td>
                                 <a href="https://us.cibc.com/en/commercial.html">
                                 <img src="https://sf-asset-manager.s3.amazonaws.com/96926/7/1524.png" alt="CIBC Connections" border="0" height="" width="100%" style="display: block; font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #3C3F44;">
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <!-- Hero Image : END -->
                           <br>
                           <tr>
                              <td dir="ltr" style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #3C3F44; text-align: left; padding-right: 0px;">
                                 <p style="margin: 0;" class="has-markdown">
                                    <br>    
                                    <br>
                                    ++FirstName++,<br><br>
                                    We are committed to being the leading commercial and wealth bank for the private economy in the U.S., working hard every day to help your realize your ambitions. Enhancing our capital markets capabilities for commercial and wealth clients is an important part of being able to deliver excellence for our clients every day. Last week, we announced that we have reached an agreement to acquire Cleary Gull, a Milwaukee-based boutique investment banking firm specializing in middle market mergers and acquisitions, private capital placement and debt advisory.
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    Cleary Gull is a well-recognized middle market investment bank. The team has advised on over 200 transactions for clients like you and has expertise in manufacturing, business services, consumer/retail and technology. 
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    We expect the transaction to close in the fall. Your relationship manager can answer any questions you have about Cleary Gull or our Capital Markets services for you in the meantime.
                                    <br><br>
                                 </p>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </div>
                     <!--[if mso]>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <!-- PRIMARY BODY : END -->
   <!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->
   <tr>
      <td aria-hidden="true" height="10" style="font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;">&nbsp;
```

Comment: If by header you big the banner image then, your image seems to load fine but you have a big chunk of text sitting above the view online and the banner which seems to be the same as the pre header? Also which version of blackberry are you testing this on? Last i heard z10 (and newer versions) have support for HTML + CSS.